# Visual Studio Code tree view setting. Get back the old view (pre 2020)

Tags: visual-studio-code

This makes me crazy! It should be trivial but I cant find in settings how to get back the old look in the file explorer window. Well it's not that old, it was just a few weeks ago.

First image shows what I want and the second image shows what I have now. To be clear **I don't want** the folder structure to show up like this: 
**routes \ admin**
or
**views \ admin**

I want it to look like in the first image.

**The question is how to get it back so it looks like in the first image. What setting is it?**

In visual Studio Code.

---

[image: Tree view I want.]

---

[image: tree view I have now.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (to open the command pallete)

Type `Open Settings (UI)` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

On the Settings search box, type `Compact Folders` and uncheck the checkbox